# Using Implicit Euler with second order differential equations

Tags: computational-physics, integration, differential-equations, calculus

We can numerically integrate first order differential equations using Euler method like this:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_n, y_n)$$

And with Implicit Euler like this:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_{n+1},y _{n+1})$$

If I have a differential equation $y' - ky = 0$, I can integrate $y$ numerically using Implicit Euler:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hky_{n+1}$$
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n\frac{1}{1-hk}$$

But how I do use Implicit Euler for second order differential equations, like for instance the equation for simple harmonic motion?
$$y'' + w^2y = 0$$

We have to integrate with respect to $y$ and $y'$. For explicit Euler the numerical integration would look like this (?):
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_n, y'_n)$$
$$y'_{n+1}  = y'_n + hg(t_n, y_n)$$

How would we do integrate using Implicit Euler instead?

Comment: As you can see in the answer: always rewrite your system as a first order one.

Comment: Please avoid cross-postings, or add links to the other places on this network, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576061/using-implicit-euler-with-second-order-differential-equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write your second order equation as a system of two first order equations. Let $y' = v$, then your equation

$$
y'' + \omega^2 y = 0
$$

becomes

$$
\begin{pmatrix} y' \\ v' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} v \\ -\omega^2 y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y \\ v \end{pmatrix}
$$

If you denote $u = (y,v)$ and the matrix as $A$, this system can be written as

$$
u' = A u
$$

Now implicit Euler reads

$$
u_{n+1} = u_n + h A u_{n+1}
$$

or

$$
\left( I - h A \right) u_{n+1} = u_n
$$

Translated back into components you get

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -h \\ h \omega^2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y_{n+1} \\ v_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_{n} \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Addendum**. It might be worth pointing out that implicit Euler is not a very good integrator for this type of problem as it will lead to artificial energy dissipation. You might be better of with what is called [symplectic Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method).

Comment: Indeed, I failed to make an even number of sign errors :) Fixed.